# All elements are null, when try to convert String to Bitmap Array

Tags: android, string, bitmap, decode

I'm trying to convert the String I get from the server to Bitmap but it is returning:

> "All elements are null"

Here is my code

```
Bitmap[] contentBitmap = new Bitmap[content.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) { //content is ArrayList<String>
    String bmString = content.get(i);
    byte [] encodeByte  = Base64.decode(bmString, Base64.DEFAULT); //byte is not null
    contentBitmap[i]    = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length); //here I get null
}

adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, contentBitmap);
```

Any help will be appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your bmString integrity.

Comment: i checked it, and yep my string was cropped, thanks!